# ASP.NET MVC returning more than expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my code, when a certain exception happens, im returning

```
Response.AddHeader("X-Status", "çãõáéí");
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "You lack permission X, Y and Z");
```

and using Postman I was surprised to see 3 things:

1. the body of the response. it should be empty.. the response should contain only headers, but the body is actually full of html/css...
2. the `Content-Type` header was only "text/html" and not "text/html charset=utf-8"
3. there was nothing indicating that "Response.HeaderEncoding" was set... whether it was set to utf8 or utf32 or big-indian...

So, how can I "make" the body empty? meaning that I wish the content of the response to be clear... Extra points if you are able to teach me to encode `X-Status` so the browser displays especial chars correctly and not like a upside down question mark...

Comment: In testing your code in a blank project, it looks like you're getting the IIS error page for 403. Still looking for a solution, but I'm not sure how you bypass those error pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It didn't seem obvious, but in order to bypass the IIS errors, you need to do something like:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
    <remove statusCode="403" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Essentially, you need to override/remove the default handler for the error code you're returning (in this case, Forbidden/403). Otherwise, your 403 response will trigger IIS's error handling and you get:

[image: IIS generic forbidden page]

which is self-explanatory, I think.

This does introduce another problem: this is site-wide. It *might* be possible to handle the response code on a per-action basis (possibly with a filter, though that may be too far into the pipeline), but I'm not sure at this point.